# "bring something down to the reception" or "bring something down at the reception"?

Tags: prepositions

Tell me please which preposition is appropriate in the following context.

> After you leave the room you have to bring the keys down **to** the reception.
>
> After you leave the room you have to bring the keys down **at** the reception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are moving the keys from place to place - that is what *bringing the keys* involves. Thus, ***to*** is the correct preposition. On the other hand, if you were telling them to *hand the keys in*, that is something that happens in one place, so ***at*** would be appropriate - or *to*, because you can think of it as *giving* the keys. So, some options are:

> After you leave the room you have to **bring** the keys down **to** reception.
>
> After you leave the room you have to **hand in** the keys **at** reception.
>   After you leave the room you have to **hand in** the keys **to** reception.

Comment: Could you please explain why you omitted the definite article before the word "reception". Is the inclusion of it before the word wrong?

Comment: I didn't explain that because it wasn't the object of the question, but I would say it is unnatural rather than *wrong*. If, on the other hand, you add the word *desk*, it's required: "bring the keys down to the reception desk". *Reception* here is sufficiently specific, it acts like a proper noun in terms of use of articles.

Comment: Generally, when you refer to an operational group within a business, you don't use the article: "Call **housekeeping** to get a new towel, or just ask at **reception**."  This holds for businesses other than hotels: "**Accounting** processes expense reports and **legal** reviews contracts."